# Update Values with incremental count

Tags: sql, delphi

My table Looks like this

```
Index   Name   Value 
1       A      value A
2       B      Value ...
3       A      Value .....
4       C      Value C...
```

Now I need to grap all records where Name = 'A' like  `select * from MyTable where Name='A';`   and  and make an Update , replace first occurence of A by A[1] and so on ....

The solution should be a stored procedure as I don't want to do this stuff on the Client side

```
Index   Name   Value 
1       A[1]   value A
2       B      Value ...
3       A[2]   Value .....
4       C      Value C...
```

I use Delphi with ADO components on MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server using an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by index) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from mytable t
     ) 
update toupdate
    set name = name + '[' + cast(seqnum as varchar(255)) + ']'
    where cnt > 1;
```

You can implement this logic wherever you want, either by calling the query on the client side or putting it in a stored procedure and calling the stored procedure.

Comment: I used /added where clause to the solution   .... from mytable t where Name='A' , works perfectly